# Changing text inside DIV removes event handler

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a table and in the first column I have a div that has an onclick event attached. When a button is clicked I want to change the text within the div but doing so seems to remove the onclick event. How can I stop it removing the event or re-add the event afterwards?

I'll post what I currently have below.

Thanks

```
var _rows = $("#tableData").find("tr:gt(0)");

    $(_rows).each(function () {

        var $me = $(this);

        $me[0].childNodes[0].innerText = "+";
    });
```

Answer (score 3):

How about just sticking to jQuery ?

```
$("#tableData").find("tr:gt(0)").children(':first-child').text("+");
```

then you don't even need a loop, `text()` does that internally for you !

Comment: this will not getting added to dynamically loaded elements. you will be probabally need to use .on or .live

Comment: @GaneshBora - seriously! How do you add text to an element that does'nt exist, and how on earth would you do that with on(), and what's the difference from the other answers in regards to dynamically created elements ?

Comment: to re-add the event afterwards means element is getting added afterwards the page loads. so we have to specifically use .on or .live method.

Comment: have posted this by reading the end line "How can I stop it removing the event or re-add the event afterwards"

Answer (score 0):

When you are using jQuery, please stick with it. Replace your code with:

```
var _rows = $("#tableData").find("tr:gt(0)");
$(_rows).each(function () {
    var $me = $(this);
    $me.children().first().text("+");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

seems to be event is bind to the elemnet which you are removing, may be you have added event to the table td elemnt and you are removing it.

to resolve the issue bind event based on class selector and also use jquery [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) or [.live()](http://api.jquery.com/live/) method.